# Question on parallelograms and area - please comfirm!

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

Alice drew parallelogram ABCD and Bob chose a point P on its diagonal AC. Then Alice drew lines EF and  GH through P parallel to the sides of the parallelogram as shown on the figure. Is it true that the areas of parallelograms DHPF and BGPE are equal to each other regardless of the choice of the original parallelogram ABCD and the choice of the point P on its diagonal?

I then came up with the following.

> My solution:
>
> No: point P will move $x$ units right and $x$ units up, so the height of each parallelogram will increase by
> $a$ and the base will decrease by $a$. If we multiply the side lengths of one of the parallelograms together:
> $$(h-a)(b+a)=bh\Rightarrow bh+ah-ab-a^2=bh \Rightarrow ah-ab-a^2=0 \Rightarrow \color{DarkRed}{h-b-a=0}$$
>
> $\color{DarkRed}{h-b-a=0}$ `does not have to be true` for example if $h=8,b=4,a=2$

However, I am not sure if my values for the height, base and $a$ are

- realistic
- possible
- actually mean something

and I can't

- prove it
- disprove it

Would you mind telling me how to prove/disprove it, and how?

#### Cheers!

Comment: Actually, it's true ...

Comment: ok @MichaelHoppe :) fair enough but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangles $ACD$ and $ABC$ are congruent, so is the pair $AGP$ and $APF$ as well as $PCH$ and $PCE$.  Enough?

Alternatively, let $a=\vec{AB}$, $b=\vec{AD}$, and $0<r<1$ such that $\vec{AP}=r(a+b)$. Then the parallelogram $FPHD$ is spanned by $(1-r)b$ and $ra$, the parallelogram $GBEP$ is spanned by $rb$ and $(1-r)a$. Now compare the cross products
$$(1-r)b\times ra\quad\text{and}\quad rb\times (1-r)a.$$

OR recall that the area of parallelogram ist the product of the two sides and the sin of the enclosed angle.